# How to check if a lua_state is closed?

Tags: c++, lua, embedding

I want to check if a lua_state is closed or not. How can I check it? I use this library as c++ lua embedder: https://github.com/lua/lua

Comment: Why do you need to check this? It seems like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

Closing `lau_State` in lua frees all alocated memory inclusive `lua_State` itself.

From Lua 5.4.2 source code:

```c
static void close_state (lua_State *L) {
  global_State *g = G(L);
  ...
  (*g->frealloc)(g->ud, fromstate(L), sizeof(LG), 0);  /* free main block */
}
```

It means closed `lua_State` points to invalid memory.

So it is left to you to manage `open`/`closed` state in threads or asynchronous tasks.